# optimize mysql select query on many to one

Tags: mysql, select, query-optimization, one-to-many

I am trying to optimize a mysql select query but I just can't work out how to do it.

I have been reading around here and any other relevant results on google but can't find anybody with quite my problem, hopefully this isn't because I have constructed really bad DB Tables

I have three tables, Table A, Table B, Table C

Table A has a one to one relationship with table B

and

Table A has a one to many relationship with table C

because I need all the information from table c which relates to each row in table A I am using a GROUP BY to condense the results down to the number of relevant results from Table A.

Unfortunately When adding the GROUP BY it causes mysql to create a tempory table which slows everything right down.

I have read about in which instances mysql will use a tempory table and it seems I should be able to make it work but just can't work out how to do it, I am hoping that I can restucture my query with the same results but without the tmp table which is making it go slow.

I also have an order in my query. If I remove the GROUP BY I get all the rows in table A as well as the accumalative results of table C BUT it does all this in a fraction of a second.

With the GROUP BY and with or without the ORDER BY, because mysql then uses a tmp table it takes anything from 2 to 15 seconds depending on any other criteria needed.

this is basically my query (although details changed for security reasons)

```
SELECT 
table_a.*, table_b.*, table_c.*
FROM `table_a` 
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_b.ID = table_a.table_b_id 
LEFT JOIN table_c ON table_a.ID = table_c.table_a_id AND table_c.deleted !='yes' 
WHERE table_a.deleted !='yes' AND table_b.deleted !='yes' 
GROUP BY table_a.ID 
ORDER BY table_a.date_added DESC
```

I have around 15k results in table a and 100k results in table c

I really need all the information from table c which relates to the rows in table a so my thoughts are if

a. I can remove the group by and accomplish the same end result then it would have removed the need for a tmp table and speeded it all up
b. Alter how I am joining the tables together so that the sorting of the results for the group by is more efficient and then hopefully remove the tmp table as well

Can I make this query more efficient or am I just stuck because of how my tables are setup?

---

Thanks for the reply.

Sorry I should have mentioned I have tried group by and order being the same value of table_a.ID but from mysql EXPLAIN this still seems to be using a tmp table.

From testing it seems removing order by and just having group by still doesn't work although order by on its own is fine, it just brings back ALL the results.

In doing the EXPLAIN though, I have noticed that possible_keys and key are both null for table_a even though table_b and table_c are both reporting using a column for possible_keys and key.

Should i be getting an indication from EXPLAIN that table_a has a key?

Matt

---

Sorry its from phpmyadmin, so not the best layout.

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  table_a     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    13297   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  table_b     eq_ref  PRIMARY,ID,     PRIMARY     3   db.table_a.table_b_id   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  table_c     ref     table_a_id  table_a_id  3   db.table_a.ID   9

Comment: please add the results of EXPLAIN to the question

Answer (score 0):

When you have GROUP BY and ORDER BY with different fields, you will pretty much always end up with a temporary table.

As a side note, You select may be producing unexpected results due to the inclusion of all fields but only grouping by table_a.ID. Records in Table C may be getting mangled.